# Installed libgdx and OpenGl in ubuntu

Tags: java, games, android, eclipse, opengl

first let me say thanks for all the help in my other questions; the answers have really help a lot.  Now I'm in the process in developing game for tablet, pc and android platform.

I have decided to use libgdx and opengl for my games in the future since I'm focusing in java; the big question is how do i installed it in Ubuntu?

Thanks in advance

p.s if i have to use eclipse in the process or terminal I'm game:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your hardware/driver need to support the required OpenGL version, you can check the version reported using

```
glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
```

The first step is to install the development libraries of OpenGL/Glut in Ubuntu:-

```
sudo apt-get install freeglut3 freeglut3-dev
```

For newer versions of Ubuntu (>= 11.10) you have to install another package because the linker does’t link anymore.

```
sudo apt-get install binutils-gold
```

For libgdx its really hard to state all things here but please refer to this [link](http://louissimons.com/2013/06/setting-up-libgdx-on-ubuntu-13-04/) to learn how to configure and install.

Comment: If i don't see the version, it means i don't have it installed?

Comment: @user253350 yes sure and also this means that you miss the drive of your graphic card. what is your graphic card?

Comment: Processor is a AMD Dual-Core Processor C60; Graphic card is a  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Wrestler [Radeon HD 6290]

Comment: Hello :) Recently i put the driver of my graphic card but some how it mess with my second extend monitor.  Instead to extend it mirror it, dose this affect the opengl installation?

Comment: gdx link broken.