# Setting up libgdx on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, java, games

I'm on ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I'm actually learning how to make games in java, I'm going to learn game development with libgdx. The tutorial says that I have to download the setup app, to put it on the desktop, and then to type on a command prompt:

cd desktop

java -jar gdx-setup.jar

The problem is that when I type "cd desktop",I see "no file or folder of this type", how can I correctly set up libgdx with ubuntu?

Thanks for your answers

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! "It doesn't work"-style error descriptions don't permit us to help you. Please edit your question and include the error message you see on the screen. If there's no message, explain what happens and what you instead expect to happen.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/432812/installed-libgdx-and-opengl-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the terminal type:

```
cd Desktop
```

The name of the Desktop folder is case sensitive. Then run the rest of the commands in the tutorial as usual.